# Proving asymptotic bounds

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, logic, asymptotics

I'm confused if the following approach is mathematically correct

Suppose I have to prove $(\log_2n)! > n^a$, where '$a$' is a constant

I can assume $n = 2^k$

Which leads to $k! > c^k$, where $c = 2^a$

The conclusion is true since factorials have a higher rate of growth than exponentials.

My doubt is, is it correct to terminate the proof there and conclude $(\log_2n)! > n^a$, or should I extend the proof until I get a correct result in terms of $n$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial links and the warm welcome, I've edited the question.